# Why my ActiveMQ is shutting down my Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, activemq-classic

I have a dummy webapp in a Tomcat container that uses ActiveMQ.

The problem I'm having is that out of nowhere the ActiveMQ shuts down and forces my Tomcat to shutdown as well.

This is the log from catalina.log:

```
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,072 - ActiveMQ Message Broker (localhost, ID:app-46388-1421875096431-0:1) is shutting down - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:560) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,072 - Caught exception, must be shutting down: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.removeShutdownHook(BrokerService.java:1950) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    Jan 21, 2015 5:35:04 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
    INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
    Jan 21, 2015 5:35:04 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
    INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-209.159.149.98-8080
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,075 - Shutting down VM connectors for broker: localhost - org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.stopped(VMTransportFactory.java:227) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,076 - Stopping connection: vm://localhost#0 - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:964) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,077 - Stopped transport: vm://localhost#0 - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:980) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,077 - Cleaning up connection resources: vm://localhost#0 - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1013) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,077 - remove connection id: ID:app-46388-1421875096431-2:1 - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processRemoveConnection(TransportConnection.java:713) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,077 - localhost removing consumer: ID:app-46388-1421875096431-2:1:1:1 for destination: queue://mydomain.mail.sender - org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.removeConsumer(AbstractRegion.java:322) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,077 - remove sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:app-46388-1421875096431-2:1:1:1, destinations=1, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, lastDeliveredSeqId: 0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 - org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.removeSubscription(Queue.java:430) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,079 - localhost removing consumer: ID:app-46388-1421875096431-2:1:-1:1 for destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic - org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.removeConsumer(AbstractRegion.java:322) - ActiveMQ Task
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,079 - Connection Stopped: vm://localhost#0 - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1023) - ActiveMQ Task
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,079 - Connector vm://localhost Stopped - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.stop(TransportConnector.java:288) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,079 - ActiveMQ Message Broker (localhost, ID:app-46388-1421875096431-0:1) is shutting down - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:560) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,079 - Caught exception, must be shutting down: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.removeShutdownHook(BrokerService.java:1950) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,081 - PListStore:activemq-data/localhost/tmp_storage stopped - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStore.doStop(PListStore.java:307) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,081 - Stopping async queue tasks - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.doStop(KahaDBStore.java:206) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,081 - Stopping async topic tasks - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.doStop(KahaDBStore.java:220) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,082 - Stopped KahaDB - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.doStop(KahaDBStore.java:246) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,082 - Checkpoint started. - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.checkpointUpdate(MessageDatabase.java:1131) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:04,090 - Checkpoint done. - org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.checkpointUpdate(MessageDatabase.java:1244) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,480 - ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (localhost, ID:app-46388-1421875096431-0:1) stopped - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:628) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    INFO 2015-01-21 17:35:04,481 - ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (localhost, ID:app-46388-1421875096431-0:1) stopped - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:628) - ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
    Jan 21, 2015 5:35:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina

DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,345 - Shutting down JMS listener container - org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.shutdown(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:190) - Thread-20
 DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,345 - Closing JMS MessageConsumers - org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doShutdown(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:303) - Thread-20
 DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,350 - remove: ID:app-46388-1421875096431-2:1:1:1, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0 - org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.doClose(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:661) - Thread-20
 DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,351 - Closing JMS Sessions - org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doShutdown(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:308) - Thread-20
 DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,351 - Failed to send remove command: javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed. - org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.dispose(AdvisoryConsumer.java:58) - Thread-20
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1259)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.asyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1251)
    at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.dispose(AdvisoryConsumer.java:56)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:615)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.shutdown(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:219)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.destroy(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:462)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:430)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:831)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:794)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:361)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1191)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:628)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:671)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1257)
    ... 29 more
 DEBUG 2015-01-21 17:35:05,352 - Could not close JMS Connection - org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:84) - Thread-20
```

This is my ActiveMQ configuration (applicationContext.xml):

```
<amq:redeliveryPolicy id="redeliveryPolicyTwoTimes" maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="2000"/>

<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost:61616" messagePrioritySupported="true">
    <amq:redeliveryPolicy>
        <ref bean="redeliveryPolicyTwoTimes"/>
    </amq:redeliveryPolicy>
</amq:connectionFactory>

<amq:queue id="jmsDestinationMailSender" physicalName="mydomain.mail.sender"/>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example  from Apache Camel how to embed an ActiveMQ broker inside a WAR application: http://camel.apache.org/activemq-camel-tomcat.html

You do not need to use Camel so you can remove that part from the WAR, but the point is that you need to setup ActiveMQ broker correctly, such as we do in the `broker.xml` file, which you have not done.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ registers its own shutdown hook and stops automatically when the process is terminating. Thus it is already stopped before you've called stop() and the exception appears.

If you are stopping it manually via Spring then you should disable the shutdown hook by setting the property useShutdownHook="false"

```
 useShutdownHook="false"
```

for refrence , Please go through the link :- 
http://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri.html

Sample code:-

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" useShutdownHook="false">
```

...

```
</amq:broker>
```